# Writing sequences in the language of arithmetic

Tags: formal-languages, first-order-logic

I am trying to write a theorem of arithmetic purely in the language of arithmetic. As a simple example, consider the theorem 
$$\forall m \quad 2(1+\cdots+m) = m(m+1)$$
This is a well known theorem of arithmetic, but the above statement is imprecise. It requires you to interpret the '$\cdots$'. How can this statement be formalized?

I emphasize that I would like to state this purely in the language of arithmetic, 
ie. using only the symbols $0,=,+,\cdot,<$ and regular first order logic symbols.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to formalize a "$\cdots$" in the first-order language of arithmetic involves using a recursive definition to give meaning to the ellipsis, and then expressing the recursively defined function using [Gödel's $\beta$ trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_%CE%B2_function).
That is, however, fairly tedious if you want to write it out completely.

In your particular case, you can reasonably hope to get away with claiming directly that the function $f(m)=m(m+1)$ satisfies the recursion equations
$$ \begin{align} f(1) &= 2 \\ f(m+1) &= f(m)+2(m+1) \end{align} $$

Comment: I am not interested in this particular case. I'm actually interested in seeing Goodstein's theorem precisely stated. 
For the current example, can you do it without first defining some function recursively? I want to avoid introducing a function symbol, which is not in the language of arithmetic. The only function symbols at our disposal are $+,\cdot$.

Comment: @Owen: The example here does not actually depend on introducing a new function symbol -- you can view my $f$ as a meta-level abbreviation because the function is defined directly by an expression. The second of my equations then becomes $$(m+1)((m+1)+1)=m(m+1)+2(m+1)$$

Comment: For the general case I think you ought to find and work through a presentation of Gödel's incompleteness theorem, which should to include a development of how to represent recursion in first-order arithmetic. As a concrete recommendation, Peter Smith's [Gödel Without (Too Many) Tears](http://www.logicmatters.net/igt/godel-without-tears/) is free and pretty good.